# Xamarin ListView .Clear() clears other listview too

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin

I have two listview named userInfoList and allUserList. The listview implements `BaseAdapter` and works perfectly. However, when I use `.Clear()` on userInfoList, allUserList gets cleared too.

Can anyone kindly point out why?

```
private List<UserInfoItem> userInfoList, allUserList;


//Populate User Data
public async void PopulateData(){
        allUserList = await ParseMethods.GetUserList ();
        userInfoList = allUserList;
        adapter = new UserListViewAdapter(this, userInfoList);
        list.Adapter = adapter;
        .....
}

Console.WriteLine("All List Count: " + allUserList.Count.ToString());

userInfoList.Clear();

Console.WriteLine("All List Count: " + allUserList.Count.ToString());
```

Output:

> All List Count: 3
>
> All List Count: 0

Comment: I have tried clearing userInfoList instead but the result is the same..

Comment: How are you initialising the lists?

Comment: yes Winney. I did that in one of my codes when I retrieved the data from parse. I'll post the part too. Is there something that I shouldn't be doing there?

Comment: Hi MattR I have added the part of the code where i added the data

Comment: Thats happens because when you are assignment list to list thats create a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your assignment in the line `userInfoList = allUserList`.

Your creating a reference.  They both point at the same data.

If you do:-

```
allUserList = await ParseMethods.GetUserList();
userInfoList = await ParseMethods.GetUserList();
```

you will find your **clear** method call at `userInfoList.Clear()` will work as expected, and leave `allUserList` with the collection still intact.

Alternatively if this is a costly data call, you could clone the result set, so that there is no reference pointer used.